# I am making a photo gallery system in which need to display uploaded photo from images folder using path stored in variable

Tags: php, string, url, path

Below is the code that retrieve data from database and show in table form. Everything is working fine except the img column. The problem I have identified but unable to resolve.

```
public function picture_path() {

   return $this->upload_directory.DS.$this->filename;

}

<?php foreach($photos as $photo){ ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td><img src ="<?php echo $photo->picture_path();?>" alt="" >

                              <div class="pictures_link">
                                <a href="delete_photo.php?id=<?php echo $photo->id; ?>">Delete</a>
                                <a href="#">Edit</a>
                                <a href="#">View</a>

                              </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo $photo->id; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $photo->filename; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $photo->title; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $photo->size; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                      <?php } ?>
```

picture_path() returns images\ images-1.jpg instead of images\images-1.jpg i.e. the space before file name so image is not being displayed.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Nico Hasse I have checked the code to see if I mistakenly added some space but that is not the case as defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT','C:'. DS . 'xampp'. DS . 'htdocs'. DS . 'cms_photo_gallery'); i get the output and there is no space on output path so unable to find the solution

Comment: Ok. So what is the value of `DS` in `$this->upload_directory.DS.$this->filename;`? Is it a constant in your app? Also to make a URL you need to build it with forward slashes, not backslashes. URLs are not the same as filesystem paths. Or maybe `$this->filename` contains a space? or `$this->upload_directory` has it? Maybe something goes wrong when that was saved, whcih adds a space by accident? We don't know, you need to break down the individual parts of that string and see where the space came from.

Comment: ADyson  defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); its the directory separator .. images\images-1.jpg if i directly put this in img src it works fine but function picture path returns a space before image file name

Comment: So then maybe `$this->filename` contains a space? Have you tested it separately?

Comment: P.S. As I alluded to earlier, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is for building a filesystem path. You're trying to build a URL, so please always use a forward slash (`/`) for that.

Comment: $this->filename = basename($file['name']);    and   public $upload_directory = "images"; this is the declaration

Comment: Ok. And what does `$file['name']` contain in this case? Output it somewhere where you could see if there was a space in it (e.g. into a textbox is an easy one). Come on, you've got to actually debug this, not just stare at the code. We can't do that for you.

Comment: Please share more details - why not dump all variables before combining them, to check for hickups? Why not start a debugger to check every input variable interactively?

Answer (score 0):

A space is being appended when the image path is saved. You can simply trim out the extra space using `trim()`.

```
public function picture_path() {

   return $this->upload_directory.DS.trim($this->filename);

}
```

Comment: Please share more details - how did you know that this is happening?

Comment: @NiceHasse It seemed like the most probable cause, as DS is definitely a PHP constant and the upload directory variable does not have space . So the only thing left was the filename.

Comment: @Leo hey man hope you don't mind accepting the answer if it has worked for you!